# Is it appropriate to GridSearchCV to pick best regression model and scaler then auto-feed to an ML pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, supervised-learning

Dataset is to predict a float outcome, no classifications. 200 samples, 50 features

imports

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Lasso
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, QuantileTransformer, MinMaxScaler,  RobustScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
```

First I instantiate a dummy pipeline

```
test_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
    ('model', KNeighborsRegressor())])
```

Then fill in a parameter grid with a few scalers and a few regressors to trial in a GridSearchCV

```
param_grid = {'scaler': [MinMaxScaler(), RobustScaler(), QuantileTransformer(), StandardScaler(), 'passthrough'],
              'model': [KNeighborsRegressor(), LinearRegression(), Lasso(alpha=0.1), Lasso(alpha=0.5), GaussianProcessRegressor()],
              }
grid = GridSearchCV(test_pipe, param_grid, cv=4)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(grid.best_params_)
print(grid.score(X_test, y_test))
grid.get_params()
```

**Out[1]:**

```
{'model': Lasso(alpha=0.1), 'scaler': QuantileTransformer()} 
0.9843408040290395
```

Then take the parameters that provided the best score and apply that to my pipeline

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', grid.best_params_['scaler']), 
    ('model', grid.best_params_['model'])])

pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

**Out[2]:**

```
Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', QuantileTransformer()), ('model', Lasso(alpha=0.1))])
```

Something about this method feels like a bad idea. Should I plot the score of each scaler/model combination and MAE/MSE and evaluate any under/overfitting here? For the chosen scaler/model:

```
print(f'Score: {pipe.score(X_test, y_test)}')
print(f'MAE: {mean_absolute_error(y_test, pipe.predict(X_test))}')
print(f'MSE: {mean_squared_error(y_test, pipe.predict(X_test))}')
```

**Out[3]:**

```
Score: 0.9843408040290395
MAE: 13.785801047280785
MSE: 352.94279168844093
```

Comment: your question is not a coding question, agree?

Comment: No, the code all works, just a question about if this methodology is appropriate or frowned upon

Comment: then your question needs to be posted at the right site, like https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info